# How to detect when app comes to the foreground in compound control

Tags: android

I am using a compound control included in my main activity:

```
<com.example.test.StatusBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="#FF333333" />
```

and the class to that is

```
public class StatusBar extends LinearLayout
```

I would now like to get an event inside the StatusBar class when my app goes to the background/foreground. The events `onPause(), onResume()`... are not working in this case as they only exist on an Activity and I am already extending my Class with `LinearLayout`
I also don't want to forward these events from the activity as I am showing this status bar on every single activity.

Is there a chance to get these events?

Thanks for your help.

Philipp

Edit: API version is 14

Edit2: It does not seem to be possible: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCustomViews/article.html - 2.3. Activity lifecycle

Comment: if you are API >= 12 you could use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#addOnAttachStateChangeListener%28android.view.View.OnAttachStateChangeListener%29 I think. Otherwise you could override `onDetachedFromWindow()` method in your custom View class. I think it will give you a callback when the app is paused.

Comment: Thanks, I also added the API version -> 14, I will take a look at tha

Comment: I tested it and it does not seem to work, the documentation (from your link) says `Add a listener for attach state changes. This listener will be called whenever this view is attached or detached from a window. Remove the listener using`, so I guess this would only be when I somehow remove my control from the activity??